# How to reload mapper xml of springboot without was restart?

Tags: spring-boot, reload, mapper

I wrote below tag in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>springloaded</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

So when modifying java source, need not restart server. 
but when modifying mybatis mapper xml, I should restart server.
I want to know how to reload xml without restarting server.
I will wait your reply.